# What is wrong with my grape vine?

Tags: grape-vine

I'm new to growing grapes and am having some problems. One of my vines is doing great, the other is not doing so well. I was hoping someone could give me some ideas of what my problem is and how to fix it. See pictures below.

[image: 2]
[image: 1]
[image: 3]

Comment: Looks like some sort of leaf miner insect.  And your other grape vine is not showing these same symptoms?

Comment: I guess the other one shows come of this same damage but its producing fruit and looks good over all.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are several problems.

Looking at the woody shot (and partially also on green shots), it seems that the grape is affected by the Dead-arm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_arm_of_grapevine), but on a so young grape, it could also be some root problems.

The leaves shows also some lacks of nutrients (the dry/red parts, the borders, the missed shots/leaves).  This could be caused by the first disease, or by some insects (but I doubt it, the greens shots and stalks seems damaged by fungus or ev. by hail; insects doesn't seem to be the primary problem).

For now, try some leave fertilizers. At beginning of spring some Sulfur will cure the fungal disease. Check also the ground and the low part of the "trunk" if you see some fungal disease (e.g. white strips).